# rJava -- NLP, java heap error

Tags: java, r, nlp, opennlp

I'm trying to run the NLP and openNLP packages in R with rJava, and I keep getting a similar error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I've already tried:

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" )
library( "RWeka" )
```

I've also tried increasing to 8g. Still running out of space and still crashing R.

I'm working on annotating a .txt file (a large one, yes, but just one file). I am trying to extract location names. Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Chances are you're trying to load the entire file into memory and process it, instead of streaming the file line by line. Change your code so that it's not necessary to process it all in one go.